# How can I convert String[] to ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning an array to an ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746639/assigning-an-array-to-an-arraylist-in-java)

I need to convert a `String[]` to an `ArrayList<String>` and I don't know how

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dir/");
String[] filesOrig = dir.list();
```

Basically I would like to  transform `filesOrig` into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746639/assigning-an-array-to-an-arraylist-in-java

Comment: Ironic that it was labeled as duplicate, even though this is more famous than the original.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
String [] strings = new String [] {"1", "2" };
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings)); //new ArrayList is only needed if you absolutely need an ArrayList
```

Comment: I don't believe that you can then make changes to this list.  stringList.remove(1) sure isn't working for me.

Answer (score 41):

Like this :

```
String[] words = {"000", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(words));
```

or

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
String[] words = {"000", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"};
Collections.addAll(myList, words);
```

Comment: Thanks.. I couldn't use `Arrays.asList` as I had to add element to list later. `addAll` worked perfectly :)

Comment: second option works

Answer (score 19):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

The list returned will be backed by the array, it acts like a bridge, so it will be fixed-size.

Comment: This answer is wrong and won't even compile.

Comment: @suriv: the only problem was `List` instead of `ArrayList` but the answer is not wrong. Creating a copy of an array to an `ArrayList` is not always necessary, sometimes you just need to view an array as a list. Mind that creating a real copy, as in `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array))` requires a memory for each element of the list. For example a 100000 `Object` array requires 800kb of RAM just for the pointers to references.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, trying to add or remove elements from this List will throw an exception.

Comment: @suriv: it's clearly stated in the answer and it's clearly stated in the documentation, in any case thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9):

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
Collections.addAll(myList, filesOrig);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can loop all of the array and add into ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>(filesOrig.length);
for(String file: filesOrig) {
    files.add(file);
}
```

Or use `Arrays.asList(T... a)` to do as the comment posted.

Comment: `...new ArrayList<String>(filesOrig.length);` prevents that the backing array has to be grown in size. Potentially faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like

> MyClass[] arr = myList.toArray(new MyClass[myList.size()]);