# Convert String results[] To ArrayList<String> alist;

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert String[] to ArrayList<String>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230929/how-can-i-convert-string-to-arrayliststring)

hi please can anyone help me I have :

```
private String results[]; 
private ArrayList<String> alist;
```

I want convert

```
String results[] to  ArrayList<String>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String s : results){
    aList.add(s);
}
```

What this does is, it constructs an ArrayList of Strings called aList: `ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>();`

And then, for every String in results: `String s : results`

It add's that string: `aList.add(s);`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Convert String Array to ArrayList as

```
String[] results = new String[] {"Java", "Android", "Hello"};
ArrayList<String> strlist = 
     new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(results));
```

Comment: The method putStringArrayListExtra(String, ArrayList<String>) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<String>)intent.putStringArrayListExtra("stock_list", strings);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) method to convert an array to a list.

E.g. `List<String> alist = Arrays.asList(results);`

Please note that `Arrays.asList()` returns a `List` instance, not an `ArrayList` instance. If you really need an `ArrayList` instance you can use to the `ArrayList` constuctor an pass the `List` instance to it.

Comment: Note that the resulting List of `Arrays.asList()` will have a fixed size, adding elements will result in an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Arrays.asList(results)
```

by default, unless you absolutely for some reason must have an `ArrayList`.

For example, if you want to modify the list, in which case you use

```
new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(results))
```