# how to access the integer array using arraylist

Tags: java, android

The error is, that it is showing a red line in `Collections.addAll(in,n)`. 
How do I solve this?

```
ArrayList<Integer> in = new ArrayList<>(); //declared array in integer type
int[] n = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.number12);
Collections.addAll(in,n); //this is not working showing error,it is not accepting
```

integers.xml

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="number12">
        <item>735895698</item>`
        <item>814895046</item>``
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: maybe this can help you `in.addAll(Arrays.stream(n).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assigning an array to an ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746639/assigning-an-array-to-an-arraylist-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work, because an `int[]`-array is not an `Integer[]`-array, which `Collections.addAll()` expectes.

here are two ways to create a list from an array. This uses a for-each loop which iterates over the array and then adds every `int` in the array to the `list`:

```
int[] n = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.number12);
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(n.length);

for(int i : n){
    list.add(i);
}
```

The other way, is to use the in Java8 introduced `Arrays.stream()`:

```
int[] n = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.number12);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(n)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you explicitly want to get an `ArrayList` you can use the following:

```
int[] n = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.number12);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(n)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: OP suggestion actually works. It's just the type needs to be the same. The Collection expect an array of `Integer` not an array of `int`

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix:

```
ArrayList<Integer> in= new ArrayList<>();//declared array in integer type
Integer[] n=getResources().getIntArray(R.array.number12);
Collections.addAll(in,n);//this is not working showing error,it is not
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3746647/1827254), the type needs to be the same.
The `Collection` expects an `array` of `Integer`, not an array of `int`